# How to use Spring Security OAuth2 to achieve third-party login in a front-end and back-end separated project

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a front-end and back-end separated project that uses token-based authentication. After the user logs in, a token is sent to the front-end, which needs to be carried in the header of every request. My project worked fine before I introduced OAuth. I recently wanted to introduce OAuth Client to only achieve third-party login functionality, but when I accessed `oauth2/authorization/github`, I got a **401** instead of a **redirect**. I have some understanding of the OAuth authorization code flow, and OAuth works fine when tested separately, but it causes problems when I introduce it into the project.

**Are there any beginner samples available for learning?**

#### OAuth2

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: 4bb638988e7ab3a....
            client-secret: 40f17217ecfca8e73f02582a137c7e7....
```

#### SecutiryConfig

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecutiryConfig {

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private TokenFilter tokenFilter;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/user/logout").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2Login().and()
                .addFilterAfter(tokenFilter, LogoutFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable()
                .cors();
        return http.build();
    }
```

#### tokenFilter

The logic of the TokenFilter involves extracting the token from the request header and querying Redis for it. If the token is not found in Redis, then the filter invokes userDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(userName) to retrieve the user and saves the user in the AuthenticationToken.Regardless of whether the user is found, the filter allows the request to proceed. The subsequent filters determine whether the login was successful based on whether there is an Authentication in the SecurityContext.

```java
authenticationToken =new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,userDetails.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

### You get 401 during authorization code flow because sessions are disabled

OAuth2 clients require sessions: to store tokens for instance and just because requests between the browser (or any other front-end) and the OAuth2 client are not secured with OAuth2 access tokens (only requests between client and resource server are). As sessions are required, CSRF protection should be activated too.

### "Best practices" for securing distributed applications with OAuht2

There is no "one" answer. It depends on the frontend being able to protect correctly tokens (which excludes Javascript based framework in a browser).

If yes, the frontend can be configured as OAuth2 client, using a dedicated library to handle flows, store tokens and authorize requests.

If no, it is currently preferred to apply the **B**ackend **F**or **F**rontend pattern where the OAuht2 client is a middleware on your server, securing communications with browsers using sessions, keeping tokens in sessions and replacing session cookie with OAuth2 access token before forwarding a request from browser to resource server. spring-cloud-gateway can be configured as BFF (as OAuth2 client and with `TokenRelay` filter)

### Considerations about Github (and other "social") identities

It is pretty likely that you can't configure your resource servers (OAuth2 REST APIs secured with access tokens) to use efficiently "social" OIDC providers: they usually issue only opaque tokens (not JWTs) and user endpoint latency doesn't make it a good candidate for introspection.

If you are fine with your Spring application being only an OAuth2 client, no Problem. But if you want it to be a resource server (make it accessible with requests secured with access tokens), you should probably spin your own authorization server instance configured to issue JWTs and with "social login" features.

Keycloak as well as almost any OIDC cloud provider (Auth0, Amazon Cognito, Azure AD, ...) have such "login with ..." features. You could also build your own with Spring Authorization Server project, but this requires quite more work.

In any case, I suggest you have a look at my OAuth2 tutorials, with a careful read of the [main README](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

Comment: Thank you for your reminder, but that is not the answer I am looking for. What I am hoping for is a best practice for using OAuth2 in a front-end and back-end separated project.

Comment: See my updated answer, but you have some more reading (quite a lot, and there is no way to skip it)

Comment: I noticed that your tutorial focuses more on how to build our own authorization server and resource server. However, I don't need them at the moment. I only need to develop an OAuth client to use GitHub's authorization server to obtain user information for login. Anyway, I appreciate your reply very much!

Comment: Maybe you overlooked it. Authorization server is a secondary concern (focused in prerequisites only). Tutorials  explain how to configure OAuth2 clients and resource servers with only Spring "official" Boot starters or with my enhanced ones (and this includes spring-cloud-gateway configured as BFF). But no doubt that after a little more reading, you'll figured out that this answer helped (and maybe even solved) your question.